# jquery scrollable

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of a up-to-date jquery plugin that does exactly what this does:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

I am looking for the core functionality:
With a click have an animation horizontally scroll another page into viewport

(no, i dont want to use THAT plugin or i wouldnt be asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to be in the slider, I use [Slides](http://slidesjs.com/) for most content, or if it's just images, I like [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/).